# inner html not changing button display in javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the value of a button and display it on the screen. I'm changing the inner HTML and using getElementByID. This seems to change the value of the button but not display it on the screen. I've searched and found similar questions, but none that seem to solve this.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Noughts and Crosses</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="message">Click a square</p>

        <ul class="gameBoard">
          <ul class="rowOne">
            <input type="button" id= "buttonOne" class= "gameBoardSquare" value=""><!--
            --><input type="button" id="buttonTwo" class= "gameBoardSquare" value=""><!--
            --><input type="button" id="buttonThree" class= "gameBoardSquare" value="">
          </ul>
          <ul class="rowTwo">
            <input type="button" id="buttonFour" class= "gameBoardSquare" value=""><!--
            --><input type="button" id="buttonFive" class= "gameBoardSquare" value=""><!--
            --><input type="button" id="buttonSix" class= "gameBoardSquare" value="">
          </ul>
          <ul class="rowThree">
            <input type="button" id="buttonSeven" class= "gameBoardSquare" value=""><!--
            --><input type="button" id="buttonEight" class= "gameBoardSquare" value=""><!--
            --><input type="button" id="buttonNine" class= "gameBoardSquare "value="">
          </ul>
        </ul>

        <div>
            <input type="button" id="buttonReset" value="RESET">
        </div>

<script src="js/tictactoe.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

and the javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("buttonOne").innerHTML = "X";

})
```

Comment: If you use input tag use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your actual HTML, `<input>` elements don't have their own HTML at all.

Instead, the text of the button comes from the `value` property & attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/47my39cj/1/)

```
<input type="button" id= "buttonOne" class= "gameBoardSquare" value="">



<script type="text/javascript">
  var elem = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
  elem.value = "button text";
</script>
```